# Python how to separate different values in same column in csv file?

Tags: python

I have a csv file that looks like this:
[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wR3t.png)

Essentially I'm trying to add each value in column E (political regime) to a list of lists, separated by the country name in column B.

So, every time Afghanistan appears, add its political regime value to a list, then when a new country appears, add those values to another list.

I also have to do this task WITHOUT pandas or numpy.

I hope this makes enough sense but here's my current code which is an infinite loop and freezes my program.

```
def read_file(fp):


reader = csv.reader(fp)
next(reader, None)
country_names = []
list_of_regime_lists = []
for line in reader:
    country_names.append(line[1])
for line in reader:
    line[4]=int(line[4])

return country_names, list_of_regime_lists
```

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You're linking an image instead of pasting part of your CSV. Also, fix your indentation.

Comment: my indentation is correct on my project. don't know why it turned out like this. also im aware i attached an image of the csv file rather than the file.

Comment: can you replace the image with data in code?

Comment: I notice that in your second `for` loop, you have `line[4]=int(line[4])`, which on its own just modifies a variable that you don't subsequently use, and you also never use the variable `list_of_regime_lists`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for a dictionary.

```py
def read_file(fp):
    with open(fp, 'r') as file:
        contents = file.readlines()
    regimes = {}
    for row in contents[1:]:  # skip header row
        fields = row.split(',')
        country = fields[1]  # column B
        regime = fields[4]   # column E
        if country not in regimes:  # check if this is a new country
            regimes[country] = [regime]  # start a new list of regimes
            # regimes[country] = {regime}  # alternatively use a set to ignore duplicate regimes
        else:
            regimes[country].append(regime)  # or add the regime to that country's list
            # regimes[country].add(regime)  # if using a set
    return regimes
```

Comment: my file is a csv file/ excel file as well as i should have two lists. one list which is essentially a dictionary of countries. another list of the political regime value for that year which is in a list of other country's political regime values. like this: country_names = [Afghanistan, Albania, etc.] and list_of_regime_lists = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0], etc.]

Comment: Those two lists can be taken directly from the dictionary, e.g. `country_names = list(regimes.keys())` and `list_of_regime_lists = [regimes[c] for c in country_names]`.

Comment: does it matter if i use csv.reader or with open(fp, 'r') as file:   contents = file.readlines() ??

Comment: Feel free to adjust the code to use `csv.reader`; I just wrote the example to not require any imports.